# Unable to verify signature created in C#

Tags: c#, java, security, rsa, x509certificate

I am creating signature using C# and verifying the signature in java.  This always returns false.  Request for helping me in identifying where I am doing wrong.

C# code for creating signature :

```
SHA256CryptoServiceProvider sha = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
RSACryptoServiceProvider key = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)privateCert.PrivateKey;
RSACryptoServiceProvider signer = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
signer.FromXmlString(key.ToXmlString(true));
byte[] signedHash = signer.SignData(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"));
```

java code for verifying signature :

```
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
signature.initVerify(certificate);
signature.update(data);
boolean retValue= signature.verify(signedHash);
return retValue; // always returns false
```

thanks
Raj

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are using the same algorithms. One is using SHA256, the other SHA256withRSA.

Try MessageDigest, as per this example:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-sha-hashing-example/

Comment: As I understand Using Signature class I can pass only SHA256withRSA, SHA1withDSA, SHA1withRSA.  Is there a way to use only SHA256 using some other classes in java.